# Spring Boot получение excel файла на компьютер клиента

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить сохранить сгенерированый на сервере excel файл на компьютер клиента?

```
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");

    List<Material>materials = materialDAO.getMaterialsList();

    HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);
    rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("№ з/п");
    rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Назва");
    rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Кількість");
    rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Од.вим.");

    for(int i=1;i<materials.size();i++){
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)i);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(i);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(materials.get(i-1).getTitle());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(materials.get(i-1).getNumber());
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(materials.get(i-1).getUnity());
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
```

Comment: Какие библиотеки используете для вашего проекта для формирования excel файла? Ну и приведите сам код как отправляете клиенту.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Этот код (сверху) для сохранения на диск. Но, насколько я понимаю, сохраняться данный файл будет на сервере. А как его передать для сохранения на компьютере клиента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примерно так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void myExcel(HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ParseException {


    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    //тут дальше создаем файл


    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode("Мой файл.xls", "UTF-8") + "\"");
    response.setContentType("application/xls");

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    workbook.write(outputStream);

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Более правильный `Content-Type` для формата Excel до версии 2007 - `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring версий 4.2 и выше для отдачи клименту XLS(X) предлагает расширять абстрактные классы [`AbstractXlsView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/AbstractXlsView.html) и [`AbstractXlsxView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/AbstractXlsxView.html).

```
public class MyXlsView extends AbstractXlsView {

    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
                                      Workbook workbook,
                                      HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // change the file name
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");

        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");
        // собираем файл
        // ... 

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("№ з/п");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Назва");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Кількість");
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Од.вим.");

        // итд

}
```

и возвращать их через `ModelAndView` из контроллера.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getReport() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new MyXlsView());
    return mav;
}
```

---

Отдать имя файла с кириллицей кроссбраузерно - отдельная проблема.
На моей памяти лучше всего работало так:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=utf8'ru-ru'" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: а в RestControllere как это сделать (без модели). Просто массив байтов кидать?

Comment: `@RestController` аналогичен паре аннотаций `@Controller` и `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: А если отправить просто массив байтов. Что с ним потом в Javascript делать?

Comment: не надо обрабатывать его JavaScript-ом. Просто пусть пользователь перейдет по ссылке и получит массив байт. С правильным `Content-Type` и `Content-Disposition` браузер автоматически начнет скачку файла.

Comment: Если вам все же нужно выполнить это действие из JS - откройте новую вкладку через `window.open(xlsReportUrl, '_blank')`.

Comment: Короче, задача такая: есть база данных материалов на складе. По нажатию на кнопку в JS надо загружать Excel документ-отчет об остатке на складе.